# Running Cmdlet with equality comparision operator

Tags: powershell

Running the following command in Powershell 7.0.3 returns true

```
[datetime]'2020-08-09' -eq 'August 9, 2020'
```

But, I want to replace the right side of the command with `Get-Date`. I wonder how I can do it. If I'm not wrong (Please correct me if I am), we can do it in bash using the by enclosing the command in ticks(`).

I've tried the Invoke-Command cmdlet but I get the same error:

```
> [datetime]'2020-08-09' -eq Invoke-Command Get-Date
ParserError:
Line |
   1 |  [datetime]'2020-08-09' -eq Invoke-Command Get-Date
     |                            ~
     | You must provide a value expression following the '-eq' operator.
```

Can someone help me out with it or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Put the command that gets the date on the right-hand side of `-eq` inside round brackets, so that part will be evaluated first before the comparison is made. i.e. `[datetime]'2020-08-09' -eq (Get-Date)`

Comment: @Theo: `[datetime]'2020-08-09' -eq (Get-Date)` returns false

Comment: @Theo: Thanks! I figured it out. I needed `[datetime]'2020-08-09' -eq (Get-Date -UFormat '%Y-%m-%d')` to put it in the correct format. You can put it in the answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @7_R3X - the `[datetime]` call gives you that date _at midnite_. the `Get-Date` call gives you that date _at the current time_. so the 1st would be `2020-08-09 00:00:00.000` and the 2nd [right now] would be `2020-08-09 07:20:21.012' ... and those aint the same. [*grin*] you would need to use `(Get-Date).Date` to get the date with the time set to midnite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare a datetime object with another, you need to make sure that *other* part is also a **datetime object**.
This is why you need to put brackets around the right-hand side of the equasion, so the command in there is evaluated first.

As [Lee_Dailey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) mentioned, the result of `[datetime]'2020-08-09'` is a date object with the time part set to 0:00:00 (midnight).

As example of how it will work is:

```
[datetime]'2020-08-09' -eq (Get-Date).Date
```

Another thing to consider is the fact that constructing the date using `[datetime]'2020-08-09'` will leave you with a datetime object that has its `.Kind` property set to `Unspecified`.
If you are comparing this to the resulting datetime object that stores a UTC date (= has its `.Kind` property set to 'Utc)', the equasion will still go wrong (unless your current timezone IS actually UTC)

We can fake this by doing

```
[datetime]'2020-08-09' -eq (Get-Date).Date.ToUniversalTime()
```

Which in my timezone would return False.

P.S. It is wrong to compare a datetime object to a formatted date **string**.
It may have worked in your case, because apparently the `.ToString()` method of a datetime object happens to format in 'yyyy-MM-dd' on your system. On different locales however comparing like this will fail .